# The parameter 'snapshot' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-dependencies

i am getting this error. i have tried putting required word but it shows new errors.
can someone please help. I'm stuck at this point.if I put required this.snapshot than it shows error for PostDetails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF0WF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rtq.png)

my code:

```
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//ignore: must_be_immutable
class PostDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
  PostDetails(List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> snapshot, {required this.snapshot});

  @override
  _PostDetailsState createState() => _PostDetailsState();
}

class _PostDetailsState extends State<PostDetails> {
  get title => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Post Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: new Card(
        elevation: 10.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(widget.snapshot["title"][0]),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    new SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      widget.snapshot[title],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            new SizedBox(
              height: 7.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: new Text(
                widget.snapshot["content"],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

update:
I'm getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR9c3.png)

update: getting error in snapshot in another file
my code:

```
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;

  late List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;

  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection("Post");

  Color gradientStart = Colors.deepPurple[700]!;
  Color gradientEnd = Colors.purple[500]!;

  passData(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    Navigator.of(this.context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostDetails(
              snapshot,
            )));
  }
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please post all code and errors as text so it can be searched, copy-and-pasted, etc. so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

The widget part of a `StatefulWidget` must be immutable. Mark your snapshot property as `final`.

```dart
class PostDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
  PostDetails({required this.snapshot});

  @override
  _PostDetailsState createState() => _PostDetailsState();
}
```

You also have conflicting constructor parameter names... not sure what you're doing with the unnamed, positional, parameter. Parameter names, even if one is positional and one is named, must be unique. Think about if you had a constructor body... how would the body know which one is which.

Comment: its still same ,showing error

Comment: I just tried it in my IDE and it's fine. Weird.

Comment: Sure you're not seeing the conflicting parameter name error?

Comment: The name 'snapshot' is already defined.
Try renaming one of the declarations. i am getting this error

Comment: That's the conflicting name error I was talking about... you have two arguments named `snapshot`... you can't do that.

Comment: also in anothe file for PostDetails i am getting error -The named parameter 'snapshot' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.

Comment: Why do you have a positional argument that isn't being used? Remove it?

Comment: im following a video tutorial. im beginner in flutter

Comment: It's cool. Welcome to Flutter! So it looks like you're not using the positional constructor parameter... `List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> snapshot` try removing that. Where you're creating an instance of `PostDetails` you'll need to create it like `PostDetails(snapshot: someSnapshot)`.

Comment: i removed that and error solved but I got new error.you can check I have added in question

Comment: The argument type 'List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'. im getting error for PostDetails

Comment: Okay so you are passing in a list of documents. so let's update the property. I'll update my answer

Comment: However the build method looks like you're using a single document. This is a very confusing bit of code.

Comment: Yeah I think you do want a single document so where you're sending in your snapshot you actually want to be iterating over the data in that snapshot which is a list of documents.

Comment: I would check your tutorial and see how they're passing in data to `PostDetails` I'm sure they're not sending in the entire snapshot.

Comment: i have added updated my ques and added code

Comment: im getting error at last line snapshot

Comment: turoial link-https://youtu.be/_ed4783G5yY

Comment: i have tried but its giving errors